# Is the $p$-norm of the fourier transform of a function greatest when its phase is constant?

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, lp-spaces, fourier-transform

Suppose $f\in L^2$ and define $g\in L^2$ by $g(x) = \lvert f(x)\rvert$. Based on numerical experiments I believe that

$$ \Big\lVert\hat f\Big\rVert_p\leq\Big\lVert\hat g\Big\rVert_p$$

whenever $p\geq 4$. How can I prove this?

---

- I do have a proof in the case when $p=2n$ for $n\in\mathbb Z$. Then
  we can write:

  $$\left\lVert \hat f\right\rVert_p = \left\lVert \hat
     f\right\rVert_{2n} = \left\lVert {\hat
     f}^n\right\rVert_{2}^{1/n}=\left\lVert f^{*n}\right\rVert_{2}^{1/n}$$

  (using the [convolution power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_power)) and likewise $\left\lVert \hat
     g\right\rVert_p =\left\lVert g^{*n}\right\rVert_{2}^{1/n}$. Then
  since we have

  $$\lvert f^{*n}(x)\rvert=\left\lvert\int_{\sum x_i=x}f(x_0)\dots
     f(x_{n-1})\right\rvert\leq\int_{\sum x_i=x}\lvert f(x_0)\rvert\dots
     \lvert f(x_{n-1})\rvert=\lvert g^{*n}(x)\rvert$$

  for all $x$, we are done.

  So I'm interested in the more general case where $p$ is an arbitrary real number (greater than or equal to $4$).
- My numerical experiments were based on the discrete fourier transform. The requirement that $p\geq 4$ comes from the example $f = (1,-1,0)$. Then

  $$\left\lVert\hat f\right\rVert_p=\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}^p+\sqrt{3}^p+0^p}3\right)^{1/p}$$

  and
  $$\left\lVert\hat g\right\rVert_p=\left(\frac{2^p+1^p+1^p}3\right)^{1/p}.$$

  Thus for this $f$ and $g$, the inequality $ \Big\lVert\hat f\Big\rVert_p\leq\Big\lVert\hat g\Big\rVert_p$ holds only when $p\leq 2$ or $p\geq 4$.
- The motivation for this question is to try to tighten the [entropic uncertainty principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropic_uncertainty) in quantum mechanics. The theorem would say that for a given position distribution and $n\geq 2$, the [Rényi entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%A9nyi_entropy) $H_n$ of the momentum distribution is minimized by the wavefunction with constant phase. (I do know how to prove that this wavefunction minimizes the *variance* of the momentum distribution, so it already gives a tightening of Heisenberg's uncertainty principle.)

Comment: Have you seen this: https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0303244.pdf ? You didn't specify what your domain is. If the functions are defined on $\mathbb{N}$ and the fourier transform on $\mathbb{T}$, then the paper I linked gives a counterexample to your question.

Comment: @mathworker21 Thanks for the link! I'd be happy with a counterexample on any domain, but I can't quite extract one from that paper. They mention that there are counterexamples to $\lVert\sum a_ne(n\theta)\rVert_p\leq\lVert\sum e(n\theta)\rVert_p$ for any $p$ not an even integer, but unless I'm missing something obvious that doesn't give a counterexample to $\lVert\sum a_ne(n\theta)\rVert_p\leq\lVert\sum\lvert a_n\rvert e(n\theta)\rVert_p$ since the $p$-norm isn't a monotonic function of the $\lvert a_n\rvert$. The rest of the paper is about $p=3$, which is of course less than $4$.

Comment: I think they're construction, with $\Lambda = \{\sum \epsilon_i D^i : \epsilon_i \in \{0,1,3\}\}$ and $a_i =  (-1)^{W(n)}$ (defined in their paper) will work for any odd integer $p$; note that indeed $|a_i| = 1$. It seems you just want a single counterexample to your question. You or I can try coding. Have you tried the very first example they gave, of $1+e(\theta)+e(3\theta)$ and $1+e(\theta)-e(3\theta)$? If I am wrong that all this stuff works for $p=5$, maybe the base-$5$ analog of all of this will work for $p=5$. Once again, if you want, I can check.

Comment: Oscar, what you are missing is that the LHS (with $a$'s) is a convex function of $a$'s, so if we want to maximize it, only the extreme values (i.e., all $|a_j|=1$) need to be considered, i.e., if you have a counterexample with $|a_j|\le 1$, we can immediately upgrade it to one with $|a_j|=1$ by moving $a_j$ along straight lines to one of the two extreme positions.

Comment: @fedja Thanks, that makes sense. I'd accept that as an answer if you could track down an explicit example.

Comment: @mathworker21 Ditto. All the references from Green and Ruzsa's papers are books so I haven't been able to check them. Do you have access to a copy of any of them?